# will Server.Transfer work in a Web Farm

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know, wether Server.Transfer will work in a Web Farm.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will. It just causes ASP.NET to restart the cycle with the new URL instead of the old, whether you're running in a web farm or not is irrelevant.